# C Programming Format Adjustment

Tags: objective-c, c, unix, formatting, vi

I am asking for some homework help. I am not asking for the answer,I just wanted to be pointed in the right direction.

I have a program in C which I am new to. I have to recreate a Unix tool using `vi`. Its job will be to read input and “neaten” it up. It reads in paragraphs of words and rearranges them such that they fit nicely onto a line of specified width, inserting line breaks as needed. A paragraph is separated from other paragraphs by one or more empty lines than changing the width with `-w` and changing to right alignment using `-r`.

Next would be to justify the text using `-j` so that every line with more than one word extends from the left to the right with max width. I need to apply integer division to calculate the total number of spaces that should have been seen by the time you finish a gap using Kevin Woods `Si = i*S/G` where `S` is the total number of spaces needed in the line, `G` is the number of gaps between words in the line and `Si` is the number of spaces that should have appeared by the end of the `i'th` gap. Lastly suppress line spacing from lines entered with more than a double line back into a double line.

The options should be cumulative—I can specify width, alignment, and skipping of blank lines together. The `-r` and `-j` flags should not be used together.

Comment: Could describe what difficulty you are having solving it ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am having a problem getting the program started. I have made the distorted paragraph for the program to fix however I do not know where to begin with the coding to fix it.

Comment: "getting the program started"? does that mean: "how do i start TO program" or does it mean "how do i start THE program"? In first case: grab THE book (Programming in C by K&R) and read, then come back

Comment: not sure, WHERE the problem is. you have the code? and you want to start the program? then you have to use the compiler and linker (f.e. gcc) to build an executable, which you can start from the command line. please elaborate on your understanding of the word "fix".

Answer (score 1):

first step: metacode

```
main(arguments)
  analyse arguments f.e. with getopt() for correctness and validity
  read the original text
  break the text into virtual paragraphs (identified by a double LineBreak)
  for each paragraph
    break it into lines of less than allowed (-w, default 80) characters

  for each line that is not the last line of a paragraph
    fill with spaces according to your algorithm and command line spezification

  print out all lines
```

second step: coding
this is your task. Please come back, when you have code, that shows us, where you are stuck.

Comment: Yes, how to start the program, I am currently reading up on getchart and putchar to utilize in it.

Comment: how to start: `./a.out` after compiling and linking